# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am following the same code from the link : http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/. But when I simply run the main method of `Spring Boot`, I see that the below error is coming. Could you please guide? I am using `Java 7`.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/websystique/springboot/configuration/JpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootCRUDApp.main(SpringBootCRUDApp.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:183) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getRequiredProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:556) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.configuration.JpaConfiguration.jpaProperties(JpaConfiguration.java:98) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.websystique.springboot.configuration.JpaConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaConfiguration.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.websystique.springboot.configuration.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ce60e74.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.websystique.springboot.configuration.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ce60e74$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a174a592.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.configuration.JpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ce60e74.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

**application.yml**

```
---
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /SpringBootCRUDApp
---
spring:
  profiles: local
datasource:
  sampleapp:
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: SA
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 10
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: create-drop
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
datasource:
  sampleapp:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 20
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: update
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add freemarker template support -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add JPA support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Hikari Connection Pooling support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add H2 database support [for running with local profile] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add MySQL database support [for running with PRODUCTION profile] -->       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin><!-- Include if you want to make an executable jar[FAT JAR which 
                    includes all dependencies along with sprinboot loader] that you can run on 
                    commandline using java -jar NAME -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**SpringBootCRUDApp.java**

```
@Import(JpaConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.websystique.springboot"})// same as @Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan
public class SpringBootCRUDApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCRUDApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**JpaConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.websystique.springboot.repositories",
entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${datasource.sampleapp.maxPoolSize:10}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    /*
     * Populate SpringBoot DataSourceProperties object directly from application.yml 
     * based on prefix.Thanks to .yml, Hierachical data is mapped out of the box with matching-name
     * properties of DataSourceProperties object].
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.sampleapp")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties(){
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    /*
     * Configure HikariCP pooled DataSource.
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties();
        HikariDataSource dataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder
                .create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        return dataSource;
    }

    /*
     * Entity Manager Factory setup.
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.websystique.springboot.model" });
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    /*
     * Provider specific adapter.
     */
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    /*
     * Here you can specify any provider specific properties.
     */
    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.hbm2ddl.method"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.format_sql"));

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.sampleapp.defaultSchema"))){
            properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", environment.getRequiredProperty("datasource.sampleapp.defaultSchema"));
        }
        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest following a good tutorial. Like [this one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). The guide you are following is basically ignoring the fact that Spring Boot is being used.

Comment: Try passing that property like this `public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootCRUDApp.class)
        .properties("datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect").run(args);` if it now complains about next property, application.yml is **not** loaded

Comment: The method SpringApplicationBuilder(Class<SpringBootCRUDApp>) is undefined for the type SpringBootCRUDApp - Your suggestion not working

Comment: @Deinum , Just for my knowledge, what makes you say that guide is ignoring the fact that spring boot is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an active profile for 2 different environments say dev/prod to resolve this issue. If you are using Eclipse create an application to start and add in VM arguments when you are trying to start the application as,

```
for dev
  -Dspring.profiles.active=local 
for production
  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

and if you are trying to run as jar,

```
 for Dev,
     java -jar SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar --spring.profiles.active=local

for Production,
 java -jar SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but have you remembered to run with a profile? That error is normally a sign that you are not.

The tutorial also says that you have run with a profile.

> While running our example [via IDE or command-line], we can provide
>   the profile information using -Dspring.profiles.active=local or
>   -Dspring.profiles.active=prod in VM arguments[for IDE] or on command-line java -jar JARPATH --spring.profiles.active=local.

The reason is that Spring needs to know which properties to use from you properties file (in this case a yml file).

Answer (score 0):

Create separate profile for default and local. It works for me.

```
spring:
  profiles: default
datasource:
  sampleapp:
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: SA
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 10
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: create-drop
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

---

```
spring:
  profiles: local
datasource:
  sampleapp:
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: SA
    password:
```

Comment: If this is different from [user3428736's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461164/3789665), please make it easier to see how so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse... Just right click on pom.xml -> Run As - > Run Configurations. Then it will open new popup window and you can see SpringBootCRUDApp under Java application...On the right side popup window ..select Arguments tab...there you can 2nd text as VM arguments..there just you paste "-Dspring.profiles.active=local".. Then Run it.. It will work...

If you are running from cmd prompt 
for Dev,
     java -jar SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar --spring.profiles.active=local

for Production,
 java -jar SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod

--Njoy

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse, to run spring boot application add profiles in VM arguments in Run Configuration,
for dev you can add
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
for production you can add
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
Please find in ScreenShot
[eclipse_spring_profile_vm_args.JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmxM2.jpg)